# Dividing objects into two piles of equal weight

Tags: algorithm

I am sure you have already heard about this problem. Given a list of natural numbers, is it possible to divide them into two piles of equal sums? If yes, write two lines with objects in each pile.

Is this some well-known problem? Does it have a name? Is it NP-Complete? If not, what is the fastest solution?

Comment: If it is NP complete, it will still have a fastest solution.  It'll just be slower.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is the [Partition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_problem) problem, which is NP-Complete. It is a variant of Subset SUM.

Which is the fastest, really depends on the data you have. For instance, if they were bounded, you could use dynamic programming etc.